# Remove maxLength set from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

As we know, `maxLength` for `EditText` is set by:

```
android:maxLength="19"
```

or programmatically. My question is that how can I remove this `maxLength` programmatically if it was set to certain length? I want to set `maxLength` to the maximum length possible.

Comment: If you don't want it then remove from the XML file and set it programmatically so that it will be more dynamic.

Comment: Try setting it to zero 0 or try find its default value.

Comment: @Kunu in my application in some cases I should set it to certain length and remove it in some other conditions. This is why I am asking

Answer (score 4):

Just try to set empty InputFilter Array for remove the Max Length.

```
etEmail.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>()
```

Answer (score 0):

In android there is EditText and sometimes you may want to limit the character input. EditText in XML layout would give you android:maxLength to do this thing but in codes you might wonder why there isn't any setMaxLength function. The reason behind this is that when you want to restrict the EditText to accept certain value, you have to filter them and this would be invoke by setFilters and thus to make our EditText to have a fixed size we shall.

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
int maxLength = 3;
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
et.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this bellow code to your `ext` file and use it away :-)

```
fun styleLimitText(text: String, length: Int): String {
    if (text.length > length) return text.substring(0, length) + "..."
    return text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { });
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try to set a maxLength property to -1

```
android:maxLength="-1"
```

or programmatically

```
int maxLengthofEditText = -1
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLengthofEditText)});
```

Comment: Setting it to -1 does not work! Setting it to Int.MAX_VALUE does though.